# BACnet PC Application:How to inquiry list of BACnet TCP/IP objects

Tags: java, c, bacnet

I have a task to communicate and read list of BACnet object and their properties from Trane Tracer summitBCU via BACnet TCP/IP. However, I don't know which BACnet services to get the list of BACnet object from BCU. Every can teach me how to do this!

Answer (score 6):

Use the WhoIs service to locate the remote devices and to obtain the binding of their device number and MAC address. Then you may use the ReadProperty service to read the Object_List property of the  device object. Now you know all available objects within the device. Finally browse the objects with the ReadProperty or ReadPropertyMultiple service.

Comment: " Then you may use the ReadProperty service to read the Object_List property of the device object." 
What a great Hint.

Answer (score 0):

The I-Am response(s) (to the Who-Is broadcast response) will give you the info from the devices, which might also include the 'network number' too - so as much as with BACnet/IP you target a physical device via it's IP address, in some cases you might also have to pass a MAC address & network number (- when as the "client", requesting to read a property from the "server"/target physical device).

Sadly, even if you can get (/automate the retrieval of) the list of objects/"OBJECT-LIST"/'OBJECT_LIST' from the devices, you'll probably have to have a manual list of the properties for each object - e.g. their property_id, and also understand what they're used for (- the name of the parent object/"OBJECT-NAME"/'OBJECT_NAME' might give a clue), either via engineer word to mouth or by reading the device's PICS statement.

And you might have to handle return errors, and maybe dropped/slow UDP packets too (- but you can try to avoid this by giving time between each subsequent request).